# Can a golang command line app install postgres and use it?

Tags: installation, postgresql-9.3, package-management

Can a golang command line app install postgres and create a database unobstrusivly without the user knowing?

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with Go.  2) Installing a database is a pretty obtrusive act, unless your users aren't paying attention.  3) This sounds an awful lot like an XY Problem. What is your _actual goal_?

Comment: My goal is to re-use code that uses an ORM in a CLI app without the user going through a set of commands to install and migrate the database. Probably not possible.

Comment: Can you use sqlite?

Comment: Perhaps, this is logic from a webapp that currently uses postgres. It's possible the ORM is somewhat agnositc to the database and I could just re-write some small areas that may be postgres specific. Is sqlite possible to install as part of building/installing a go cli app?

Comment: It is if you use https://github.com/glebarez/go-sqlite. Then it's just compiled into your go binary.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at https://gitlab.com/cznic/sqlite/ which is a source conversion of the pristine SQLite code to Go which passes the SQLite's enormous test suite.